# Is there a shortcut for (self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I write too much of this code :

```
self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height
```

Is there shortcut for this? Something like `self.frame.y_plus_height`?

If there is, I'm not sure if that good news or bad news for all the times I wrote the full sentence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
CGFloat res = CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame);
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000955-CH1g-F17149).

EDIT: according to explanation from rob mayoff (see comments) this is a little more expensive than simply summing `origin.y + size.height` in code.

Comment: I saw this helper in past, never used it.
The question if it effect performance ? or the compiler optimize it to inline code of frame.origin.y + frame.size.height ?

Comment: If i take a wild guess i would say it does exactly the same as `origin.x+size.height`. Found a nice blog on this (also about `CGRectGetMaxY`...): [CGGeometry](http://nshipster.com/cggeometry/). So yes, performance should be the same.

Comment: It is a little more expensive than `CGRect frame = self.frame; CGRect res = frame.origin.y + frame.origin.height;` because `CGRectGetMaxY` first calls `CGRectStandardize`.

Answer (score 3):

There's a great category on `UIView` created by [nfarina](https://gist.github.com/nfarina).

Check it out [here](https://gist.github.com/nfarina/3412730).

Using this category, you can get the "max Y" or "bottom" of a view like this (where `self` is a view):

```
CGFloat maxY = self.$bottom;
```

This category is really awesome because it enables you set to frame properties easily, too. In example, to move the view over to the right 3 points, you can do this:

```
self.$x += 3.0f;
```

Comment: cool. 
from there I also saw this (maybe cleaner..) :
https://github.com/AlexDenisov/FrameAccessor

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is asking for Objective-C, but for those using Swift and stumbling upon this question, you can just create a CGRect extension:

```
extension CGRect {   
    func maxYinParentFrame() -> CGFloat {
        return self.origin.y + self.size.height
    }
}
```

You can then use it anywhere.

```
let mySize = myView.frame.maxYinParentFrame()
```